# HttpWebRequest times out once executed after SQL Insert (Dapper)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, timeout, httpwebrequest, dapper

I am reading data from remote service via `HttpWebRequest`. Received JSON message is temporarily stored as a `List(Of Customer)` and subsequently inserted into a table in Azure SQL using Dapper. Application runs as an ASP.NET with .Net Framework 4.6.2 hosted in Azure App Service. So these are two steps:

A. Get data via HTTP request and store as `List(Of Customer)`

B. Insert `List(Of Customer)` into Customer table in Azure SQL using Dapper.

This works fine until I try to read and insert another set of data in same procedure:

C. Get data via HTTP request and store as `List(Of Payment)`

D. Insert `List(Of Payment)` into Payment table in Azure SQL using Dapper.

Problem: Second HTTP request (step C) always times out. I have done multiple tests. Here are my observations:

1. Both HTTP requests take usually 2 to 3 seconds to complete when executed independently.
2. Changing the order of steps to A, C, B, D works perfectly. Multiple subsequent requests A, C, A, C, ... work as well. This proves there is no remote server issue.
3. HTTP request timeout comes up only when it is preceded by SQL Insert.
4. I have separated A+B into one function and C+D into another one and trigger them by two separate buttons via GUI. Timeout comes up.
5. When C+D is executed after A+B but with 1 - 2 min delay all is fine. Seems that the less data is inserted in step A+B the smaller delay for C+D is needed to execute properly.
6. After executing A+B any other HTTP request to the same server (as A) always times out, even if requested URL does not exist. Does not matter if the other HTTP request was triggered via same browser window, other one or even from other PC (different asp.net session)
7. Once any other HTTP request mentioned in previous point is cancelled (browser window which has triggered it will be closed or redirected to other page) without waiting for the timeout and without delaying of 1 - 2 min, C+D will work fine. Even triggered few seconds later. Just only the first request times out.
8. I have tried to increase `ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit` and `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` however they have already been set to `Int32.MaxValue`.

This demonstrates some link between SQL inserts and subsequent HTTP request. However this seems hard to believe and I would point at some more general issue like memory leaks, etc.

EDIT:

Trying to investigate it further. Using the original scenario A+B+C+D, once number of rows returned by the first HTTP request was limited, it started to work. Originally remote service returned 18.000 rows. Seems like 10.000 is number when it starts to work (some executions still run with error). With 9.000 rows in step A code runs without any issues. Naturally SQL inserts in step B need less time.

Comment: It seems a security permission of the the web service that control max size of data. Contact the web admin  who can modify these parameters in web.config.

Comment: Cannot agree as once database inserts are skipped data can be read from remote server without any problems. See my observation no. 2.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False` for web service requests in steps A and C solved the problem.

However still don't know why it helps and what is the reason of the underlying issue.

Comment: But you have a lead into it. Is it a bug? Are there subtle nuances you were missing?

Comment: @clifton_h Absolutely yes. Trying to find out more at the moment. Any suggestion how to debug it?

Comment: In the meantime I have updated to .Net Framework 4.7.1 (from 4.6.2) and problem is gone. Spoke with API vendor and they has not deployed any changes since problem was discovered.